# Will you help me? i Keep getting error code 1064 and i dont understand why

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I keep getting an error code 1064
using Mysql workbench

----------Code-----------

```
use sql_invoicing;

select
  'Total Invoice',
  sum(invoice_total) as 'Total Sales',
  sum(payment_total) as 'Total Payment'
from
  (
    select
      i.number as 'Invoice number',
      i.client_id,
      c.name,
      i.invoice_total,
      i.payment_total as 'Total Payments',
      pm.name
    from
      invoices i
      left join clients c on i.client_id = c.client_id
      left join payments p on i.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
      left join payment_methods pm on p.payment_method = pm.payment_method_id
    where
      pm.name is not null
    order by
      client_id desc
  ) as 'R'
```

I am not able to figure out what the syntax error is :(.

Thank you in advance for your help